# Exception no such bean definition

Tags: java, spring

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'testDao' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
at com.test.main.java.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:30)
```

this is my main class which is calling bean testDao .

```
public class TestMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,
            ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, NullPointerException {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "springNew.xml");
        TestDao dao = ctx.getBean("testDao", TestDao.class);

        Test test = dao.getTest(1);
        System.out.println(test.getName());
    }
}
```

"THIS is >>>testDao file"

```
package com.test.dao.java;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.test.java.Test;

@Component
public class TestDao {
    static PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    Connection conn = null;

    private Connection getConnection() throws SQLException,
            ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, NullPointerException {

        if (conn == null) {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb", "postgres",
                        "postgres");
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        return conn;

    }

    /**
     * @param testId
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     * @throws NullPointerException
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public Test getTest(int testId) throws SQLException,
            ClassNotFoundException, FileNotFoundException, NullPointerException {

        conn = getConnection();
        try {

            conn = getConnection();
            ps = conn
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM testdb.testtab where id =?");
            ps.setInt(1, testId);
            Test test = null;
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                test = new Test(testId, rs.getString("name"));
            }

            return test;
        } finally {
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

AND this is >>>>springNew.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd "
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">

       <!-- <context-annotation-config/> -->
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.test.main"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Could you paste a snippet of you springNew.xml?

Comment: @AnantLaxmikantBobde-I already had pls scroll down

Comment: in your `springNew.xml` there is no bean defined as `testDao`

Comment: @MohammadFaisal - I have given package name of my main class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You scan the package "com.test.main" for beans. You bean is in package `com.test.dao.java`

Change:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.main"/>
```

to

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.dao"/>
```

Comment: sea I scan main for bean and in main I have given getbean which will redirect to testDao

Comment: @PalakChugh Think you do not understand the component-scan. There you have to add the path where your beans are.

Comment: ok are u sure coz before this i have done ..and it worked can u provide me documentation where it is written

Comment: @PalakChugh see here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your spring xml

```
<bean name="testDao" class="com.test.dao.java.TestDao" />
```

Answer (score 1):

change 
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.main"/>` 
to 
`<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>`

Comment: but my main class is in package com.test.main

Comment: Component scan should be performed over Beans (Classes) annotated with `@Component, @Service, @Repository` etc. So com.test would do the trick, you can set com.test.dao too.

Answer (score 0):

on top of

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.main"/> to  <context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
```

following

```
  @Repository
    public class TestDao{
     * @param testId
     * @return
     * @throws SQLException
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     * @throws NullPointerException 
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public Test getTest(int testId) throws SQLException, 
     ClassNotFoundException,FileNotFoundException,NullPointerException  {

            conn = getConnection();
        try {

            conn = getConnection();
            ps =conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM testdb.testtab where id 
              =?");
            ps.setInt(1, testId);
            Test test =null;
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next())
            {
                test = new Test(testId, rs.getString("name"));
            }

    return test;
        }
        finally
        {
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            conn.close();
        }


       }
        }
```

Should solve your issue

Cheers Anant

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple and a frequently occurring error while using spring. The problem is that your IDE is not finding a proper class to create bean object for a service, repository or an entity while building the project. Make sure that you have defined the proper bean name for the classes. If the error still occurs, try refreshing your application by selecting the project and clicking 'F5' button or by closing and opening the project. You can do Maven Update in eclipse. By right clicking on the project > Maven > Update Project.

Regards